# Angularjs allow one decimal number with after

Tags: angularjs, regex, html, angular-validation, angularjs-ng-pattern

```
   <input type="number"
                           name="content"
                           md-auto-focus


                           ng-model="vm.model.content"
                           ng-required="{{vm.required === null ? true : vm.required}}"
                           ng-attr-ng-max="{{vm.max}}"
                           ng-attr-ng-min="{{vm.min}}">    <div ng-message-exp="['required','min']" ng-if="vm.min != null">
                            <span data-translate
                                  translate-value-length="{{vm.min}}">min</span>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-message="required" ng-if="vm.min == null">
                                <span data-translate>required</span>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-message="number">
                                <span data-translate>numberOnly</span>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-message="max">
                            <span data-translate
                                  translate-value-length="{{vm.max}}">max</span>
                            </div>

                    </div>
```

this is short version of my code.

as you can see here,

https://regex101.com/r/fvPBTW/1
i use same regex.

It accepts 44.44, 44,

but not 44. , 44.444,44.44.44, 44.44.

I think because of number feature.

But i want to be only entered number and one decimal with number after it.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
<input type="number" name="content" md-auto-focus ng-pattern=/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1})?$/>
```

This will accept only
4 ,
44 ,
4.1 ,
4.2 ,
444.2

But not
4. ,
4.23 ,
4.444 ,
444.23 ,

Comment: No, it did not do it. Because 4. , 4.23 , 4.444 , 444.23 , are accepted by  `type=number` You only removed 1,2 and it made it accept only one  numer after decimal point. It did not change anything.

Comment: Yes , but you have validation via ng-pattern=/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1})?$/ so it doesn't matter , in your case it might be default validation by HTML5 , please check that.

Comment: how can i do this

Comment: @vegan What does not fit your needs in his answer? In my opinion, it exactly does the job.

Comment: I want only numbers to be entered. but show error message for 4. , 4.23 , 4.444 , 444.23, 44.44., 44.44.44.